# How can i query lat/long value from sqlite database and show on Google map

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps

How can i query lat/long value from database and display the marker on that location?
this is my code,  it works fine when i set lat/long

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.branchmap);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView1);


      mc = mapView.getController();
          String[] coordinates = {"13.694317","100.601592"};
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

            p = new GeoPoint(
                    (int) (lat * 1E6), 
                    (int) (lng * 1E6));
            mc.animateTo(p);
            mc.setZoom(17); 


            mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark1);
            itemizedOverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable);
            OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(p, "", "");
            itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
```

but when i want to query  it doesn't work, where should i put this part of code

```
try {
        ChannelDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new  ChannelDatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
        newDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c1 = newDB.rawQuery("SELECT lat,long FROM " +
                tableName , null);

        if (c1 != null ) {
            if  (c1.moveToFirst()) {
                do {

                    latitude =Integer.parseInt((c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("lat"))));
                    longitude = Integer.parseInt((c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("long"))));
                    p = new GeoPoint(
                            (int)(latitude *1E6 ), 
                            (int)(longitude *1E6 ));
                }while (c1.moveToNext());
            } 
        }
```

Comment: What is the client application written in?

Comment: sorry for missing that information, i'm working on android :)

Comment: use overlay class and set icon to specific retrieved point

Comment: i've just added my code, the top part works fine but when i want to get the lat/long from database it doesn't work at all --

Comment: You need to be more specific than "doesn't work at all" - does your application crash? Exceptions? Do you get bogus data? Have you tried logging the output you get? Have you ensured that the DB looks like you expect it to look? It's pretty hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        ChannelDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new  ChannelDatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
        newDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c1 = newDB.rawQuery("SELECT lat,long FROM " +
                tableName , null);

        if (c1 != null ) {
            if  (c1.moveToFirst()) {
                do {

                    latitude =Integer.parseDouble((c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("lat"))));
                    longitude = Integer.parseDouble((c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("long"))));
                    p = new GeoPoint(
                            (int)(latitude *1E6 ), 
                            (int)(longitude *1E6 ));
                    //Write a code to display this point on google-map
                }while (c1.moveToNext());
            } 
        }
```

**Try this code**